# Ember.js: Which one should I choose between Namespace, Service, and Util?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm now working on Ember CLI application. Now checking the strategy for implementing Authentication.

Now, I plan to create Auth.js, which would maintain the login state and can perform actions.

For example, in [Balanced-dashboard](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-dashboard/blob/master/app/auth.js), they are using "Namespace", but [Travis-CI](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-web/blob/master/app/utils/auth.coffee) put it in Util folder.

I also feel like Ember.Service is appropriate for putting Auth.js.

It seems both Namespace and Service are kind of Alias of Ember Object.
So, I'm wondering which of them to choose.

What kind of rule I should apply?

Comment: I am new to ember too so don't take my word for granted but I implemented authentication as service. Utils should be like tools.

Comment: Hi Keo, thank you for your comment. I've decided to use Ember.Service.

Answer (score 1):

I actually just answered a similar question [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090325/ember-js-redirect-in-router-if-certain-condition-is-satisfied-in-controller). Long story short: don't waste your time and use [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth), you will save hours of work :) It is a very flexible library that can handle different authentication/authorization mechanisms in parallel and across different tabs of the browser.

Otherwise yes, Ember services are the way to go!

Comment: Actually I'm switching from Ember-simple-auth to own Augh logic because I needed to depend on Torii and Ember simple auth token. I was not so sure they would be stay updated since Torii has not implemented Facebook's new API.  After all, I will go for Ember.Service. Thank you for your suggestion!